# Using two mouse events after each other

Tags: javascript

I am creating a canvas alike  without using canvas tag , by creating new div each time mouse is down, i can't figure out how to run a second event. 
Like mousedown then mousemove event where the seconed event occur only after the first one is true?
also if you can help with the  offset coordinates

```
var paintbox = document.getElementById("canvas");
var start = function() {
    paintbox.addEventListener("mousedown", drawOnCanvas);
};
var newColor = document.getElementById("colorPick");
var drawOnCanvas = function() {
        var newClick = document.createElement("div");
        newClick.setAttribute("id", "smallDiv");
        newClick.style.backgroundColor = newColor.value;
        newClick.style.width = "10px";
        newClick.style.height = "10px";
        newClick.style.position = "absolute";
        paintbox.appendChild(newClick);

    }
```

Comment: Attach the mousemove event in the mousedown handler function (as well as mouseup listener), and remove it in the mouseup event handler function.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve? Drawing boxes on click? Drawing multiple boxes while dragging? Drawing lines between two clicks?

Comment: Either bind on mousedown /mouseup events or use a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: when i click the mouse i create a small div with background and append it to the main div this is what i reached . what am trying to do now is after mousedown and while moving it keeps creating div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the handler on the `mousemove` event instead of `mousedown` and in the handler check whether the mouse button is down.

It would be better to move the 10px/position style settings in a CSS class. Also, don't generate elements with the same `id` attribute value: that generates invalid HTML. Use a `class` instead.

For the positioning you can use the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the event object.

Finally, as the events will be triggered on the small divs when you make small moves, an extra check might be necessary to verify the mouse is still in the paint box.

```js
var paintbox = document.getElementById("canvas");
var start = function() {
    paintbox.addEventListener("mousemove", drawOnCanvas);
};
var newColor = document.getElementById("colorPick");

var drawOnCanvas = function(e) {
    if ((e.buttons & 1) === 0) return; // Mouse button is not down
    // Extra check to see we are well within the box boundaries:
    var box = paintbox.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (e.clientX - 5 < box.left || e.clientX + 5 > box.right 
         || e.clientY - 5 < box.top || e.clientY + 5 > box.bottom) return;
    var newClick = document.createElement("div");
    newClick.className = "smallDiv"; // Don't create duplicate ID; put CSS in class
    newClick.style.backgroundColor = newColor.value;
    paintbox.appendChild(newClick);
    newClick.style.left = (e.pageX-5) + "px";
    newClick.style.top = (e.pageY-5) + "px";
}

start();
```

```css
#canvas {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.smallDiv {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Color: <input id="colorPick" type="color"><br>
<div id="canvas"></div>
```